# Store addresses in bytes variable

Tags: solidity, bytes, code

I need help with storing a bytes value.

```
contract StoreBytes {
    bytes public addresses;
    function addMe() external {
        // TODO Add msg.sender to addresses.
    }
}
```

What I want is that msg.sender is added to `addresses`, basically `addresses` to be a chain of addresses.
Example:
If 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 calls `addMe()` and then 0x1230000000000000000000000000000000000000, `addresses` would look like:
`0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000001230000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

I don't know why I can't fix this :D.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why would you take this approach, as opposed to something more standard like making `addresses` and array of addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Alex that what you're asking is a bit suspicious and there may be a better way to achieve whatever you're doing. But since this is a Q/A forum and not a product review...

try:

```
abi.encodePacked(addresses, msg.sender)
```